# Have a command with multiple arguments

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, discord.net

```
<Command("add")>
Public Async Function cmdAdd(<Remainder> ByVal num1 As Integer, <Remainder> ByVal num2 As Integer) As Task

    Dim sum = num1 + num2
    Dim user = Context.User
    Dim channel = Context.Channel

    Await channel.SendMessageAsync($"{user.Mention} the sum of the two specified numbers are {sum}")

End Function
```

Not necessarily my command but I would like to know how I make a command have multiple arguments. If I remove everything after the , it works but once I add another argument it doesn't work.

Comment: ALWAYS read the documentation: *"The RemainderAttribute leaves the string unparsed, meaning you do not have to add quotes around the text for the text to be recognized as a single object. Please note that if your method has multiple parameters, the remainder attribute can only be applied to the last parameter."*

Comment: Given that your parameters are not type `String`, does it make sense to use the `Remainder` attribute at all? I'm not sure as I have never used Discord.NET. I just did a couple of obvious web searches based on the content of your question and the results seem to suggest not.

Comment: For future reference, *"it doesn't work"* is NEVER an acceptable description of a problem. You need to specify what it actually does do, not just that it doesn't do as intended. There would have either been a compilation error or a run-time exception and both provide error messages intended to help you diagnose the issue. If you want us to diagnose the issue then you have to provide all the relevant information and that error message is obviously relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having now read the relevant documentation and gained an understanding of what that `Remainder` attribute does (which you should have done before posting a question at all), it is clear that you should not be using it at all in this context but, in contexts where you should use it, you should only use it on the last parameter.